# Yii2 - Stop Field validation if calendar is open

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, yii2

I have a Yii2 active form which includes a field with datepicker. My form is using following attributes:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'campaign-form',
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'fieldConfig' => [
                'options' => ['class' => 'gg-create-group'],
                'labelOptions' => ['class' => null],
            ],
            'options' => [
                'autocomplete' => 'off',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

I have a field using jquery datepicker, the issue is each time I click on the arrows to navigate through the months in the calendar, client validation is triggered an a error is shown:

[image]

I need to stop the error message if the calendar is open and I am using the calendar navigation.

I know I can turn off client validation using:

```
enableClientValidation => false
```

But I want to keep client validation. I am wondering if Yii javascript script: $yiiform has an option to do that?

Comment: What will happen if you set
`'enableClientValidation' => true,
'validateOnChange' => false` in the array of form settings?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase yes I found it, just publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I can use validationOnBlur, if I set it to false on specific field it fixes the issue.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'client_end_date', 
['validateOnBlur' => false])->textInput(['readonly' => 'readonly']); ?>
```